# Existe alguma alternativa ao comando mysql_connect do PHP?

Tags: php, nginx

Estava tudo funcionando bem até aparentemente a instalação do Nginx dizer que o meu comando `mysql_connect` tinha o seguinte problema:

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50173 Library:50536 in /home/tal tal tal

Comment: Primeiro que o problema não está no "comando" e sim na instalação de versões diferentes d ebiblioteca no sistema. Acho que o caminho natural é usar mysqli_, que é feito para MySQL. Agora, se for usar outras arquiteturas de DB, o PDO é uma alternativa a se considerar, como respondido. Se não pretende usar outra base, o mysqli_ faz mais sentido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, o PDO.

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php

Porém esse erro acontece quando a versão do php e das bibliotecas do mysql estão diferentes.

Ou você atualiza o PHP e recompila ele ou o mysql.

Você pode tentar instalar/atualizar o php5-mysqlnd.

Apenas para constar, isso é um **warning**. Sua aplicação não irá deixar de funcionar.

O PHP está avisando que as bibliotecas nativas do php e dp mysql estão em versão diferentes.

Nota importante é que o mysql_connect está **deprecada**. Hoje, por orientação do PHP, deve-se usar ou o PDO ou o **mysqli_connect**

Comment: Sua resposta está de certa forma correta, mais e se for uma aplicação já em uso, com centenas ou milhares de arquivos? Reescrever tudo?

Comment: Vou melhorar a resposta. XD

Answer (score 3):

Recomendo também o uso do PDO, pois sua camada DAL não fica dependente de qual versão de banco de dados usar, ora, um dia você pode migrar sua aplicação para POSTGRE, MSSQL...

Enfim, uma outra alternativa é usar o Mysqli_connect():

```
$link = mysqli_connect("host","usuario","senha","db");
```

Fonte:

> https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: Sim sim, inclusive o mysql_connect está deprecada.

Comment: mas mesmo assim muita gente insiste em usar, é bem comum ver perguntas com sistemas com falha de sqli, ainda postam o link do site... lamentável